# Certificate Pinning on AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, lambda

**Certificate Pinning on AWS Lambda**

Can handler functions in AWS lambda, invoked by API Gateway, reach down into the connection layer of the request at all to access what certificate was used to establish the SSL/TLS connection on the client side? I'd like to implement a certificate pinning strategy for the API I'm building as I've found a dozen ways in which SSL without pinning can be bypassed and the data in my API is not social media posts.

**Any Alternatives if not possible?**

If Lambda functions don't have access to the connection layer is there a comparable way of further enforcing security and not simply saying "SSL is enough"

**Last Resort**

If Lambda doesn't give me access to the certificate info of the client connections I'll have to resort to asymmetric encryption.

Comment: What does *"I've found a dozen ways in which SSL without pinning can be bypassed"* actually mean?  How do you "bypass" an unimplemented authentication mechanism?   Are you aware that before the server can ask for a client cert, it needs to be aware of the CA(s) against which it can authenticate the client cert? (API Gateway isn't.) Or, that the client doesn't actually present a certificate *at all* if the server doesn't ask for one? (API Gateway doesn't.) There's no client certificate for the system to tell you about.

Comment: @Michael What do you think it means? Man in the middle. Certificate chain forgery. Forwarding spoofed HTTPS request right before HTTP redirects to HTTPS. If you believe SSL can't be breached then lets stop the conversation right now.

Comment: I never suggested SSL can't be breached, but none of the issues you mentioned are really mitigated by the subject of the question at hand, which is client authentication. API Gateway already doesn't support HTTP without TLS.  And, of course you can still use HSTS... and with a custom domain name and certificate, you should be able to use [HPKP](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Public_Key_Pinning) as well, but these are also unrelated to client certificates... so I'm trying to understand that aspect of what you are saying.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot When you do a TLS/SSL handshake with API gateway are you saying the client never sends their cert? "Are you aware that before the server can ask for a client cert, it needs to be aware of the CA(s) against which it can authenticate the client cert?" I'm not sure I understand that comment. How can you establish TLS connection without the client sending their cert? To encrypt the connection you need their cert. What I'm trying to do is access that cert and see if it matches the one in my expected list (Cert Pinning). And yes it DOES mitigate the issues I've described.

Comment: *"How can you establish TLS connection without the client sending their cert"*  Easily.  The client generates the PreMasterSecret, and encrypts it with the server's public key, and both parties now share a known secret value they use to continue the process of negotiating symmetric encryption. The client certificate is never sent unless the server sends a client certificate request -- which includes the supported types of certs *and* the DNs of the specific CAs that the server will trust against for the client's cert. API Gateway has no way to configure the acceptable CAs and requests no cert.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thank you for the detailed answer. Could you post this as an answer with the thesis/subject being "Cert pinning is not possible on Lambda"?

Answer (score 1):

An AWS Lambda function doesn't have a direct connection with an HTTP request, it can be invoked by a lot of things, e.g. an SNS subscription, or a simple SDK invocation. Or, and that's I guess what you're aiming at, you can invoke a Lambda function via the AWS API Gateway.

So if you want any HTTP or TLS details in your Lambda function, you need to make sure that the API Gateway is somehow injecting that data into the payload that's going to the Lambda function. I'm not sure if that's possible, a deep dive into some [API Gateway documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started.html) will probably help you further.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I meant invoked through API Gateway. I haven't found anything about Cert access so I'm leaning on that it might not be possible period

Comment: The API Gateway is a high level service, so I wouldn't be surprised if low-level HTTP/TLS data is not accessible. Alternatively, you could setup your own 'API Gateway' using some language of choice (e.g. NodeJS) and invoke your Lambda function in the code. This way you have full access to the low level HTTP process. The app can e.g. run in Elastic Beanstalk or an EC2 instance.

Comment: Yea it makes sense. You can't have your cake and eat it. My setup needs to run in lambda for the serverless benefits. I'm gonna explore the docs to see what I can push from the Gateway into the response.